# Query DSL appending BooleanExpression to an existing BooleanExpression with Path<?>

Tags: querydsl

I’m  trying to append two BooleanExpression.
One is a regulate BooleanExpression, the other is created out of a Path.
I think my usage of the Path is wrong. My code:

```
public static Path<?> getPathByColumnName(String columnName) {
    Path<?> retval = null;      

    QProfile p = QProfile.profile;

    if (columnName.equals("name")) {
        retval = p.name;
    } else if (columnName.equals("account")) {
        retval = p.account.name;    
    } else if (columnName.equals("isPublic")) {
        retval = p.isPublic;
    } else if (columnName.equals("datavendors")) {
        retval = p.dataVendors.any().name;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

The Path is then sent to the following method

public static BooleanExpression getFilterPredicateByFilterAndPath(Path path, FilerType type, String filter) {
        BooleanExpression retval = null;

```
    if (path instanceof StringPath) {
        if (FilerType.CONTAIN.equals(type)) {
            retval = ((StringPath)path).like(filter);
        }               
    } else if (path instanceof BooleanPath) {
        if (FilerType.EQUAL.equals(type)) {
            retval = ((BooleanPath)path).eq(Boolean.valueOf(filter));
        }
    }       

    return retval;
}
```

Then I’m trying to abbend the recived BooleanExpression to the regulare one. This does not work. Any Ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an Exception? Also how do you try to combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The usage of Path was correct the error was in a different part of the code.